# Non-prime value chosen for u in DGK encryption

Tags: public-key, homomorphic-encryption

In DGK encryption, one of the parameters of public key is value u where it is a small prime with minimum length l+2. It is not obvious for me what is the security compromise if u is not prime. Any help and idea appreciated.